# Swift 5:- App ID not found. Add a string value with your app ID for the key FacebookAppID to the Info.plist or call [FBSDKSettings setAppID:]

Tags: swift, xcode, facebook

After updating xCode from 12.4 to 12.5.1 we start to face crashing problem with Facebook SDK, we are using Swift package manager in our APP, but we received this message

```
    Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'InvalidOperationException', reason: 'App ID not found. Add a string value with your app ID for the key FacebookAppID to the Info.plist or call [FBSDKSettings setAppID:].'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1aab5b298 0x1be8b5480 0x102ca6d84 0x102ca6f04 0x102cd1828 0x102cd37a4 0x102cd2b58 0x102cd24f4 0x102cd0690 0x102cd078c 0x10241e638 0x102696ea8 0x102696f10 0x1acf7e418 0x1acf87954 0x1acf845c4 0x1acf83b8c 0x1acf781f4 0x1acf77584 0x1ad441ba8 0x1ad41d7f0 0x1ad4a0bcc 0x1ad4a53f0 0x1ad49c6dc 0x1aaada8f0 0x1aaada7f0 0x1aaad9b44 0x1aaad4060 0x1aaad3818 0x1c11d9570 0x1ad3ff0e8 0x1ad404664 0x1028adf58 0x1aa7b2140)
libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'InvalidOperationException', reason: 'App ID not found. Add a string value with your app ID for the key FacebookAppID to the Info.plist or call [FBSDKSettings setAppID:].'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

We did not get any answer until now.

Answer (score 4):

I found this answer and my problem solved

[Facebook Github](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/issues/1745)

just update your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` with that code

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

// Initialize Facebook SDK
        FacebookCore.ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

}
```

Comment: Using Firebase 10.x FacebookCore has been replaced for FBSDKCoreKit